# Searching within Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, search

I've had some problems with searching in Xcode, what is the best way to find and locate a **method** or **class** within a certain project?

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

command-shift-O will bring up the "open quickly" box, which searches textually and symbolically.

Comment: Wow that's neat too.  Wow, never knew all this.

Comment: nice to know you can think of an "it would be nice if..." then search SO to find out it exists!  command-shift-O is a go for XCode 4.6...now I just have to memorize thousands of methods...is there a shortcut for that?

Comment: This is my favorite shortcut now.

Answer (score 5):

Press ⇧+⌘+O to open the 'Open Quickly...' dialogue window.

From there you can type any symbol name or filename to quickly zoom around your project.

Unfortunately, it doesn't do wildcard or partial searching (much to my frustration) so you need to know the name (or at least the beginning of the name) for it to be much use.

You can use it to open system symbols or headers too, eg, just type `UITableView` to view the header for it.

Comment: it's now command+shift+O in XCode 4.3.1 up through XCode 4.6. Thank @pshah for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name of the method or class, a really easy way is to type it in whatever document you are in, then hold command and double-click the text. XCode will jump directly to the definition of whatever you double-clicked (even if it is not part of the project).

Comment: Will this work even if the method or class is not imported into the current document?  I hope you know what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

**Project Find** with the type of search set to **definitions** works well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to find the definition of a class from where it's being used, you can right click over the class name and select "Go to definition"

This will take you to where the class/function is defined

Alternatively there's "Find in project"

Comment: How do you mean "never worked correctly" what do you expect and what do you get?

Answer (score 2):

Pressing ⇧+⌘+F will open up **Project Find**.  Type in what you want to find, and then in the drop-down next to it select "In Project" and press "find."

Voila!  It should group the results by file for you.

Answer (score 1):

Look on the left bar, you have a smart folder called "Project Symbols." When you click on it, it will display all the symbols (eg. classes, methods, properties) available in your project. You can even search in this folder by entering a term in the box in the upper right corner.

Comment: That's a neat tip, never knew about it!

Comment: @Joe Blow and @Matthew, I was referring to Xcode 4 being "buggy", not Xcode 3.